# Hibernate flush_before_completion work like post flush or pre flush?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an Hibernate Interceptor that implement a `postFlush()`. From my understanding, post flush is the data has been saved into database but it is subject to rollback before commit is invoke. If I have a hibernate configuration that look something like this:

`<property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</property>`

Do this means save data into database before commit? Which is the same thing as post flush? Will this cause the hibernate interceptor `postFlush()` call during pre flush stage?

Answer (score 1):

The property hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion is used for "Container Managed Transaction (CMT)" or JTA, if you're using JDBC Transactions it is not relevant.

If set to true, a flush will be performed during the before completion phase of the transaction, sending all data to the database (a rollback is still possible). This flush is not managed by the hibernate session.

If set to false the automatic session managed flush of hibernate is executed before the commit and consequently the postFlush will be called.

The `postFlush()` method of the Hibernate Interceptor will only be called after the hibernate managed Flush is executed and before the transaction is committed.